# C# how to modify this method to return only with matching criteria?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an existing method of generating a list of every operators. I would like to modify it, to only display operators who are not in a so called 'Inactive' role- this information comes from OperatorType table, column: Role

The existing code:

```
public static List<TPPROperatorDetails> GetOperators()
{
    return DataHelper.DbTPPRTracer.TPPROperators.Select(
        op => new TPPROperatorDetails{
            Id = op.Id,
            FullName = op.Name, 
            UserName = op.UserName, 
            Designation = op.Position, 
            OperatorTypes = ParseOperatorType(op.UserType),
            SignatureImage = op.SignatureImage 
        }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: So do you need a JOIN from your OperatorDetails table to your OperatorType table? It's hard to help you with the limited information you've given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Where method. Something like this

```
public static List<TPPROperatorDetails> GetOperators()
{
    return DataHelper.DbTPPRTracer.TPPROperators
        .Where(op => ParseOperatorType(op.UserType) == "Inactive")
        .Select(
          op => new TPPROperatorDetails{
            Id = op.Id,
            FullName = op.Name, 
            UserName = op.UserName, 
            Designation = op.Position, 
            OperatorTypes = ParseOperatorType(op.UserType),
            SignatureImage = op.SignatureImage 
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: @Slappywag yes, I do. Well spotted ;)

Comment: In the where clause op is not defined just until later :/

Comment: I had to modify slightly, as op.UserType is an integer.
.Where(op => op.UserType != 4)

Thanks everyone!